# AndEngine with Box2D Extension

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, game-physics, physics-engine

I am newbie to AndEngine. I have done some research and found two extensions for Box2D. One is developed by Nicholas Gramlich itself: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension
and the other one is developed by Real Mayo: https://github.com/RealMayo/AndEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension

Now, I am confused which one should I use? Can anyone explain me what's the difference in both of these and which extension should I use?

regards,
Syed Umair.

Answer (score 1):

Use the one developed by Nicholas Gramlich.

I browsed the RealMayo extension, it only has 1 commit. It must have been uploaded once by RealMayo, and he didn't make any change there since then.

Comment: ummm. Thanks for your reply. Your point seems reasonable, but it might be the case that Real Mayo have developed the extension and then committed it and Nicholas Gramlich have been developing while committing the code. What you say?